# Angular2/4 Module build failed: Error

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using [Angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter). I need to move all these sources (except the `package.json` file) to `frontend_src` folder. I did it, I replaced all paths within the project but when I'm trying the `npm start` command (after `npm install` of course) I'm getting this (I replaced path to project with the `{{project_path}}` here, the path is correct):

```
ERROR in ./frontend_src/src/main.browser.ts
Module build failed: Error
    at new FatalError (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint\lib\error.js:31:23)
    at Function.findConfiguration (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint\lib\configuration.js:55:15)
    at parseConfigFile (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:44:24)
    at resolveOptions (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:35:27)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:139:17)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./frontend_src/src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./frontend_src/src/polyfills.browser.ts
Module build failed: Error
    at new FatalError (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint\lib\error.js:31:23)
    at Function.findConfiguration (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint\lib\configuration.js:55:15)
    at parseConfigFile (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:44:24)
    at resolveOptions (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:35:27)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\{{project_path}}\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:139:17)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./frontend_src/src/polyfills.browser.ts
```

How you can see, there is no explanation where is the problem. I tried to google it but all similar issues have the explanation why compilation was failed.
I tried the clean install and `npm cache clean --force` command.

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have also moved tslint.json into your client folder. You could move it back to where it was (usually at root of your project work-folder), or create a new mini tslint.json there with

```
{
    "extends": "./node_modules/shared_library/tslint.json"
}
```

You may also checkout issue here: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader/issues/57

as well as https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader/issues/22

I tried specify `configFile` Option in webpack config, but it does not seem working.